# How to retrieve data from VCard using swift

Tags: xcode, swift3, qr-code, vcf-vcard

I'm working on QR code scanning. Using the following swift code, the data in the QR code is getting printed in the console.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate
{
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    @IBOutlet weak var square: UIImageView!
    var video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        if metadataObjects != nil && metadataObjects.count != 0
        {
            if let object = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            {
                if object.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode
                {
                    print(object.stringValue)

                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "QR Code", message: object.stringValue, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okey", style: .default, handler: nil))
                   /* alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Copy", style: .default, handler: { (nil) in
                        UIPasteboard.general.string = object.stringValue
                    }))
                */
                    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    if metadataObjects.count > 0
                    {
                        print("-------------------------------------------------")
                        self.session.stopRunning()

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
        // Creating session
       // let session = AVCaptureSession()

        // Define capture device
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            session.addInput(input)
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }

        let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        session.addOutput(output)

        output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

        output.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]

        video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        video.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(video)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: square)
        session.startRunning()        
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
FN:John Peter
N:Peter;John
TITLE:Admin
TEL;CELL:+91 431 524 2345
TEL;WORK;VOICE:+91 436 542 8374
EMAIL;WORK;INTERNET:John@ommail.in
URL:www.facebook.com
ADR;WORK:;;423 ofce sales Center;Newark;DE;3243;USA
ORG:xxx Private limited
END:VCARD
```

Now what I want is, how to retrieve the data in the VCard format specifically, like getting first name, last name, email id, mobile number, etc. A similar question to this is asked before, but it was in objective-c. I don't know how to do this swift 3. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [CNContactVCardSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactvcardserialization) (macOS 10.11+, iOS 9+)

Comment: Checked it, but could not find the relevant solution.

Comment: There are only two methods in the class (besides `descriptorForRequiredKeys`), one for encoding one for decoding. It's like `JSONSerialization` but much much simpler.

Comment: I see. Thats cool.

Comment: How to save vcard in contact. Actually i am working on QRCode reading tool and getting vcard data in same format. I have to add this contact. Please help..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a sample code from Playground I used. It's not the best, but You'll get the idea:

```
import UIKit
import Contacts

var str = "BEGIN:VCARD \n" +
"VERSION:2.1 \n" +
"FN:John Peter \n" +
"N:Peter;John \n" +
"TITLE:Admin \n" +
"TEL;CELL:+91 431 524 2345 \n" +
"TEL;WORK;VOICE:+91 436 542 8374 \n" +
"EMAIL;WORK;INTERNET:John@ommail.in \n" +
"URL:www.facebook.com \n" +
"ADR;WORK:;;423 ofce sales Center;Newark;DE;3243;USA \n" +
"ORG:xxx Private limited \n" +
"END:VCARD"

if let data = str.data(using: .utf8) {
    let contacts = try CNContactVCardSerialization.contacts(with: data)
    let contact = contacts.first
    print("\(String(describing: contact?.familyName))")
}
```

The output from `CNContactVCardSerialization.contacts(with: data)` is an array of `CNContact` ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontact)).

Comment: Thanks. Somehow managed to get all data. only thing is, Im using this code to get address   "print(contact?.postalAddresses[0].value ?? String()) " and it displayed the address like this " 
<CNPostalAddress: 0x125234230: street=145 xxx Center, city=Newark, state=DE, postalCode=19711, country=USA, countryCode=, formattedAddress=(null)>" can you tell me how to get the country name, state, etc individually.

Comment: postalAddresses is an Array of CNPostalAddress objects https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cnpostaladdress . Please check the documentation, there are properties just for this. I can’t post the code since I’m on mobile for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check Updated answer for swift 4 of Mateusz Szlosek

```
 var str = "BEGIN:VCARD \n" +
  "VERSION:2.1 \n" +
  "FN:John Peter \n" +
  "N:Peter;John \n" +
  "TITLE:Admin \n" +
  "TEL;CELL:+91 431 524 2345 \n" +
  "TEL;WORK;VOICE:+91 436 542 8374 \n" +
  "EMAIL;WORK;INTERNET:John@ommail.in \n" +
  "URL:www.facebook.com \n" +
  "ADR;WORK:;;423 ofce sales Center;Newark;DE;3243;USA \n" +
  "ORG:xxx Private limited \n" +
"END:VCARD"

func fectchContact(){
  if let data = str.data(using: .utf8) {
    do{
      let contacts = try CNContactVCardSerialization.contacts(with: data)
      let contact = contacts.first
      print("\(String(describing: contact?.familyName))")
    }
    catch{
      // Error Handling
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Here's another *update*: `str.data(using: .utf8)` will never fail. You can also use non-optional `Data(str.utf8)`